# Ошибка при выводе в python(TypeError)

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, графы

Реализовал алгоритм поиска в ширину по графам, но программа выдает ошибку

```
next_v = graph[V]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Не понимаю где я мог напутать типы данных
Функция:

```
from collections import deque

queue = deque()

def bfs(start,goal,graph):
    opened = deque([start])
    closed = {start : None}
    while opened:
        V = opened.popleft()
        if V == goal:
            break
        next_v = graph[V]
        for   i in next_v:
            if i not in closed:
                queue.append(i)
                closed[i] = V
    return closed

start = 'A'
goal = 'K'
closed = bfs(start,goal,graph)
```

Граф выглядит примерно вот так:

```
{'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'],    
'B': ['A', 'E'],    
'C': ['A', 'D', 'F']...
```

Comment: А вызов функции покажите

Comment: добавил вызов  функции

Comment: Я запустил на ваших данных, ошибка не воспроизводится

Comment: Скорее всего где-то вы неправильно делаете graph который передаёте потом в функцию

Comment: Добавил импорт и сделал пустую queue, а то без этого не запускается

Comment: Да, виноват, перепроверил, оказалось ошибка в словаре

Comment: Такое бывает )  Главное, что вопрос решился